# React native appstate using to check user online and offline

Tags: react-native

I am newbie to React Native, I am developing messaging app on react native. How can I implement functionality to change user online/offline status if the appState is Active/inActive and exactly in which page (at the root/index) or after login at HomePage, will it be global? used across all the pages in application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native itself offers AppState and you can easily check there in your App.js if the app is currently in the background or just active. If the app is active, then you can call your backend function to set the online state to true. Since you are doing this in your root file (App.js), the listener works across all files.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppState, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const AppStateExample = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      // TODO SET USERS ONLINE STATUS TO TRUE
    } else {
     // TODO SET USERS ONLINE STATUS TO FALSE
    }

    appState.current = nextAppState;
    setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    console.log("AppState", appState.current);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Current state is: {appStateVisible}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If your question has been answered, please do not forget to mark it as an answer. Thx!

Comment: I was just looking for this. Thank you

Comment: how can I also handle the case in which the app is closed?